# Send FCM notifications to multiple device using the latest http api

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send a notification to multiple devices.

For a while I have been using the legacy API and sending message to multiple tokens using the "registration_ids" parameter in a single http request.
But, firebase  decided that they will depreciate it starting june, 2024. So that is why I am looking for an alternative.

Since I need to target my users conditionally based on interactions I can't use Topic, And I am not sure but seems like groups only allows maximum 20 tokens?

I decided not to go with topic for my technical limitations but group messaging is in my mind.

My current implementation is just sending a request for each token of users. But I am scared about scalability of this method. Is there any throttling on firebase side for sending multiple requests?

So my question is, are there any better way to do this with the latest HTTP api?

I have tried sending request per token to firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The versioned API indeed no longer has a separate endpoint or method for sending messages to multiple users/tokens in one call. You will need to call the API for each token.

When you call the API over HTTP/2, this is not nearly as inefficient as many developers think - so I recommend giving it a try before worrying about scalablity.